# Bradbury story about immortal kid?

Tags: story-identification, immortality

I am pretty sure RB wrote the story wherein other kids notice he is too good throwing a baseball for his apparent age and I loved this idea that it is other kids, through observations of mundane things like being too good at sports, detect something unusual about him. Looking for the name of the story.

I just watched a TV episode of Ray Bradbury Theater called "Tomorrow's Child" which had a kid born into the 4th dimension and who appeared like a geometric solid (a pyramid) to us. ChatGCP  gave me the title but either Chat was wrong or they changed the story completely for TV.

So my question is, Is "Tomorrow's Child" indeed the story or is there another one with an immortal kid who is good at baseball?

Comment: *'The Shape of Things'* (AKA *'Tomorrow's Child'*) is published in full here; https://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/69722/pg69722-images.html. There are no mentions of baseball

Comment: Well, you watched Tomorrow's Child so you know that's not the answer ;) No idea about the baseball story though.

Comment: ChatGPT is renowned for 'hallucinating' completely fictitious stories and then appending a totally random author.

Comment: Bradbury's "Hail and Farewell" has a boy who is perpetually 12 years old. He's not particularly good at baseball, but he gets discovered because the other 12 year olds in town grow (and he doesn't), and so he doesn't get picked for baseball games any more..

Comment: @Valorum: I suspect they made a hard right in the TV adaptation -- no way I personally made up the baseball idea, I would be so proud. I would like to read the story.

Comment: @ClaraDiazSanchez: RB Theater also did Hail and Farewell w/josh savino wearing a sort of old-fashioned hat. In the beginning we see a kid mentioning josh always winning in games (not specifically baseball) and getting all As.

Comment: Duplicate of [Short story about a boy who doesn't age and moves periodically from town to town](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/80107/short-story-about-a-boy-who-doesnt-age-and-moves-periodically-from-town-to-town)

Comment: @Valorum I was able to easily have GPT-3 hallucinate 10+ endings for the videogame "Inside" (scifi, so on-topic here ;)). The game I think actually has 2 endings, one hidden, but what's cool -- and scary -- is that the endings GPT-3 hallucinated were all credible; they seemed like something the designers could have added to the game. And all it took was me asking "what are the 10 secret endings of the game Inside?". This makes GPT-3 extremely unreliable; not sure if they fixed it for GPT-4.

Comment: (Just checked: GPT-4 is more resistant to this, but if you insist "no, I'm sure there are 5 alternate endings, what are they?" we're off to the races and it'll happily hallucinate some for you)

Comment: Ray bradbury theater episode https://youtu.be/RWipP1vcMvM?si=Yqe90VSZ6B_gOiTB

Answer (score 10):

This is ["Hail and Farewell"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?58387) by Ray Bradbury.

Willie isn't too good at baseball, but he is apparently immortal and spends his time moving around the country being taken in like a stray by different families and then moving on once people begin to notice that he isn't aging.

> How tall they stood in the sun. In the last few months it seemed the
> sun had passed a hand above their heads, and they were golden toffee
> pulled by an immense gravity to the sky, thirteen, fourteen years old,
> looking down upon Willie, smiling, but already beginning to neglect
> him. It had started four months ago:
>
> “Choose up sides! Who wants Willie?”
>
> “Aw, Willie’s too little; we don’t play with “kids.”

Comment: And assuming this is the correct answer, a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/80113/20774

Comment: @Valorum: It is a dupe. Funny that story mentions not kids detecting his "precocious"  baseball skill but the tv adaptation has kids mentioning grades and other games angrily. Perhaps someone else told me about the story and he interpolated baseball skills despite the story having him excluded from playing because he is too young.